# Why do random slabs stay dry in the rain?

Tags: everyday-life, water, atmospheric-science, weather, granulated-materials

The image below shows the slabbed area I can see from my work window

[image: Outside my window]

Whenever it rains some of the slabs stay dry however, it is never consistent which ones. Can anyone explain why this happens to satisfy my curiosity?

Comment: An interesting experiment could be to record how often each slab stays dry after each rain. Maybe a simple pattern emerges. Alternatively, it might be worth checking the dry slabs - maybe they have a different thermal contact to the ground than the others, or are slanted to allow water to run off quicker.

Comment: Do you really mean that some slabs don't get wet at all, or that some slabs dry out more quickly (and more completely) than others after  the rain has stopped? What evidence do you have that it is different slabs each time?

Comment: I think, there is a positive feedback loop: dry tiles warm up faster, and warmer tiles become dry faster. So, random temperature fluctuations are amplified to form random pattern of dry slabs. I have no evidence to back this assertion though.

Comment: they do not dry faster,  they just don't seem to get wet

Comment: It is also interesting that the slabs under the benches are wet.

Comment: @ahemmetter I'd so there would be consistency in the slabs that remain dry bit this is not the case

Comment: I think this may be related to the state of the slabs before rain. I can imagine that some slabs have better contact to the ground thus they are relatively wet all the time. While other slabs have bad contact to ground thus they are relatively dry before rain. When light rain comes,  relatively dry slabs absorb water into its inner part thus show up as dry, while relatively wet slabs can not absorb as much water thus show up as wet.  This can be explored with experiments. For example, mark those dry slabs, then before next rain, wet some of them preemptively.

Comment: Try (carefully) knocking on some of the tiles with a small hammer or hard object: do some of them sound loose or have hollow spots underneath them? This could give some insight as to whether or not they have good thermal contact to the ground.

Comment: It is an intriguing phenomenon. However, I am sceptical about your claim that some slabs remain dry but that it is different slabs each time. Even if this issue is cleared up I am **doubtful that a definitive explanation can be offered without further evidence from observations or experiment**. Several plausible suggestions could be made, but I think there can be no conclusive answer based on the current evidence.

Comment: Another plausible explanation is that they are not on a really even ground and  some of them drain because they have a tiny  angle with the horizontal, so that they dry up before the bulk. Dependent on the slabs, when the sun heats them the angles change and different slabs can drain. You can test this with an accurate horizontal lever, after each rain.

Comment: Different actual materials which look the same when dry? ( great question! I have those look-out-the-window-and-ask-why type questions too. )

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because based on the comments it seems like any answer would just be purely speculative. More information, experiments, etc. are needed to provide a sufficient answer to this question.

Answer (score -2):

If the OP had not mentioned that it is not consistently the same tiles that stay dry, I would have tended to agree with @anna v's conjecture about tiles being tilted. However, in view of this OP's remark, let me speculate that those tiles stay dry which have deeper seams around them, so water runs off from them more efficiently. The depth of the seams can change from time to times because pedestrians might  transfer dirt with their feet from one place to another.

EDIT (08/26/2019): One more reason in favor of my speculation: in several places, there are narrow dry strips along seams.

Comment: If it was about the walking patterns of pedestrians then wouldn't you expect these areas to be connected somehow?

Comment: @AaronStevens : I don't see why. The picture does not seem to suggest that there are some stable traffic paths, so I would think dirt could be transferred from place to place pretty randomly.

Comment: That is what I am saying. I wouldn't expect people to walk around randomly. Typically areas like this have typical walking patterns. (I didn't down vote btw)

Comment: @AaronStevens : I respectfully disagree. We see "typical walking patterns" when we have snow, grass or soil, where people can gradually reshape the surface, and this does not happen with hard tiles.

Comment: Typically, such slabs are laid on sand, with no grouting between the slabs, so the tilt of each slab can change over time. But I agree with @Aaron that we need more information.